# Entity Framework Code First - Ignore Base Class

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a model as follows:

```
public class User : System.Web.Security.MembershipUser
{
public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When my database is generated I want the Entity Framework to ignore MembershipUser and only generate a table named User with the two properties from the User class. I've tried the following to no avail.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Ignore<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser>();
}
```

Comment: what is wrong with modelBuilder.Ignore<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser>() ? It didn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`NotMappedAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.notmappedattribute%28VS.103%29.aspx) attribute is your friend:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMd)]
public class User : System.Web.Security.MembershipUser
{
    ////read description bellow code
    //static User()
    //{
    //  var type = typeof(User);
    //  TypeDescriptor.AddProviderTransparent(
    //    new AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider(type), type);
    //}        

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    internal class UserMd
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if code first processes the metadata automatically by itself, try the above, and if it doesn't work, attach the metadata manually (i.e. uncomment the commented lines).

**Update**
I do like the above solution better, but if it's too verbose for you, use the [`StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType>.Ignore<TProperty> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671225%28VS.103%29.aspx) method:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var config = modelBuilder.Entity<User>();
    config.Ignore(u => u.UserName);
}
```

Comment: When used with the static constructor this works. Pretty ugly though. I'd love to see a more elegant solution if one exists.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but the first solution only removes the first property. I've tried adding several properties to the internal class. Comment, Email, IsApproved etc. Only the property listed first is removed from the database. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @MarkS. 1) I've updated my answer with the 'more elegant solution' you asked for. 2) Make sure the properties you declare in the body class is of the same pattern as in the `MembershipUser` class (i.e. return type, get/set access modifier etc.)

Comment: This is definitely an answer.  But I disagree that `NotMappedAttribute` is your friend.  My entities frequently don't even know that EntityFramework exists, and therefore couldn't use EF Attributes if they wanted.  They don't even know they're Entities, lol Shhhh.  So I prefer the Fluent API better, especially the use of `EntityTypeConfiguration`

Comment: @Suamere that's one of the most common cases `OnModelCreating` is there for. In your scenario you should use `OnModelCreating` indeed, to keep your entities clean.

Answer (score 8):

There are two options for you. One is to ignore all the base class properties by calling `Ignore` for each property.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(u => u.ProviderUserKey);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(u => u.LastActivityDate);
    // and so on for all base class properties
}
```

Other option would be to use composition to retrieve a `MembershipUser` instance from your `User` class. Here `User` class **is not inherited** from `MembershipUser`.

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }

    public MembershipUser MembershipUser
    {
        get
        {
            // create an instance using the available properties and return
        }
    }
}
```

And map as follows

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Ignore(u => u.MembershipUser);
    modelBuilder.Ignore<System.Web.Security.MembershipUser>();

}
```

Comment: I frequently agree with the tip to Prefer Composition Over Inheritance.